# php in_array doesn't output the result

Tags: php, arrays

```
$testarray = array("Computer", 30.00, 123, 321");


if(in_array('Computer' , $testarray)){
  echo "yes!";
}else{
  echo "no!";
}
```

Guys, my in_array doesn't display yes output when in the array I have the computer value inside. Why is that so?

Comment: [If you happy and you know it `Syntax error!`](http://www.tim.id.au/blog/wp-content/uploads/2007/09/syntax-error.jpg)

Comment: Remove the `"` after `321` and try again.

Comment: Yes! extra " in the array definition after 321. Remove it, and it works.

Comment: @StephanB be careful when editing code in questions, because what you edit *may* be part of OPs problem rendering possible answers useless and leaving possible future readers in a wtf state.

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error in the first line, change it to

```
$testarray = array("Computer", 30.00, 123, "321");
```

or

```
$testarray = array("Computer", 30.00, 123, 321);
```

depending on if you whant the last value to be integer or string

Comment: Fixed, but it still display no instead of yes

Comment: @user3322610 The above [works just fine](https://eval.in/102679). So either you didn't share your actual code or something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You try this?

```
$testarray = array("Computer", 30.00, 123, 321);
if(in_array('Computer' , $testarray)){
   echo "yes!";
}else{
   echo "no!";
}
```

Just a syntax error. Enable PHP display_errors to see this error.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$testarray = array("Computer", 30.00, 123, 321);


if(in_array('Computer',$testarray )){
  echo "yes!";
}else{
  echo "no!";
}
?>
```

Your syntax is be wrong!!!